# Can't resize or move windows on Raspberry Pi

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, resize

I am using the Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+ and there was recently an update( I did not record what it was doing or what it was called) and upon reboot it mentioned that there was a previous version saved somewhere(did not take note of where this was at). Not thinking much of the update I tried to move windows around and they would not move. I found to try the *Alt* button and dragging and that is not working.

When I open up a tab for the terminal, or Idle the window drops down in the top left corner below the taskbar. When the internet is opened the window appears the top right corner. When texteditor is opened it is opened with only a little of the top of the window showing in the bottom of the screen.

I am using HDMI connection to a Sony TV, 2.4G Keyboard. Not sure what other information you will need. Along with this update the Raspberry Pi "Berry" in the taskbar has dissappeared and replaced with an imaginary icon. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I'm unsure why the issue occurs, however a quick fix I found out was to go to Appearance Settings, Click the 'Defaults' tab and select an option.

Comment: No, didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of detail inspired by Amozark's answer. This on fully-updated Buster-10 on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1

I did find a cause in my case: Openbox Configuration Manager (obconf) let me set window colors, decorations, etc., but disabled min/mix/close/sticky buttons and windows cannot be dragged.  How I got obconf to show when right-clicking on desktop, I don't know, I was trying to adjust overscan and font sizes.

The problem can also be recreated by opening a terminal window and running /usr/bin/obconf in which merely choosing a theme will cause the symptoms.

The fix click path is:

1. Applications Menu button
2. Preferences
3. Appearance Settings
4. Defaults (tab)
5. Click one of "Set Defaults" (three choices depending on your screen size)
6. Press "OK" or just close window.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. I had customized my appearance and the shortcut keys stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

This still appears to be an issue unfortunately.  I have a Pi 3B+ with the latest firmware and a fresh installation of the default 32-bit OS with Openbox.

After trying a few times and ending up with locked windows with all the keybindings in place, the fix here was to manually copy the default configuration file from /etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml to ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml and then setup the number of workspaces required directly from the Desk Pager settings.

Kevo's fix works but I have some specific customisations to font sizes etc and obviously these get overwritten when you switch to one of the default options.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem after upgrading from Buster to Bulleye.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Pi 4 and I fixed it using your fix plan. However I really wanted to customize my environment, so I've spent some time investigating this issue. To get into this problem, the Openbox Configuration Manager (obconf) should be opened by calling context menu on Desktop Pager item on your Panel. If you launch obconf from terminal or "Run" menu item - it never happens. The problem occurs because obconf does NOT copy default configuration file /etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml to ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml and update it with new configuration items. What it does instead is it dumps all the configuration from the Configuration Manager to a new, clean ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml, disabling all the defaults, including ALL mouse key bindings.

If you want to customize your windows manager - launch obconf as I mentioned above. I'll report that bug to Raspberry Os bug tracker soon.